# Scroll Lock and Numb Lock Icon Notification in Auto Hot Key - AHK

Tags: scripting, windows-10, autohotkey

I need a script that will put specific icon(that I specified) in the system tray when Scroll Lock or Numb Lock(different icons) is active. Also the script needs to hide icon when Lock or Numb is not pressed.

So far I got this:

```
If GetKeyState("Numlock", "T")
    Menu, Tray, Icon, Shell32.dll, 174

~NumLock::
If GetKeyState("Numlock", "T")
    Menu, Tray, Icon, Shell32.dll, 174
Else
    Menu, Tray, Icon, Autohotkey.exe, 1
return
```

This is working but default AHK icon is still present in system tray; it should be hidden when Numb Lock or Scroll lock are not active.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From the help documentation:

> The tray icon can be made to disappear or reappear at any time during the execution of the script by using the command `Menu, Tray, Icon` or `Menu, Tray, NoIcon`.

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_NoTrayIcon.htm

Please see if the following works:

```
If GetKeyState("Numlock", "T")
    Menu, Tray, Icon, Shell32.dll, 174

~NumLock::
If GetKeyState("Numlock", "T")
{
    Menu, Tray, Icon
    Menu, Tray, Icon, Shell32.dll, 174
} Else
    Menu, Tray, NoIcon
Return
```

Comment: If I change `Menu, Tray, Icon, Autohotkey.exe, 1` with `Menu, Tray, NoIcon` it only works once and stops.

Comment: You also need to explicity add `Menu, Tray, Icon` before your custom icon.

Comment: OK, so I have created two scripts. One is for NumLock and the other is for ScrollLock. They are the same except for the GetKeyState values, one has "Numlock" and the other has "ScrollLock" respectably. When I use only one script at the time there are no problems, but when I try to use both of them at the same time things get buggy. Second script stops registering when keys are pressed.

Comment: In my experience the most recently started script will intercept the keyboard hook preventing it to be used in the other script (except it's running in a lower priority or the previous script is running in admin mode) and this is probably the reason for this behavior. Therefore I'd use SetTimer in both scripts to toggle the tray icon.

Comment: That's another question. I'd ask a new question in that context after accepting this answer if it's working in one script.